# Wordpress function to display all posts without pagination with a cateogory ID of 20?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

If this displays posts with category ID of 20 with pagination

```
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat=20');
```

how do I display all posts with category ID of 20 **without** pagination and without going into Dashboard -> Reading -> Blog Posts Show at Most?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work like this.

```
<?php
query_posts(array('cat'=>20,'posts_per_page'=>-1));
?>
```

This one is even better as it does not affect the original loop.

```
<?php $posts = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>20,'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
```

Comment: where should I add this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead and write your own loop.

Comment: Can`t find a good example.  Do you mean something like this "<?php
$wp_query->set(‘orderby’, ‘menu_order’);
$wp_query->set(‘order’, ‘RANDOM’);
$wp_query->get_posts();
?>

Comment: Huh? I mean replacing the word `query_posts` with the word `get_posts`. The word in my answer is a link to a page full of example code.